# Indenting within table column

Tags: tables

I have the following table (using booktabs):

```
\begin{table}
\caption{Table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ccccc}
\toprule
& \multicolumn{4}{c}{Lags}\\[\defaultaddspace]
 & 5 & 10 & 15  & 20 \\[\defaultaddspace]
 EUR/USD &  &  &  &  \\[\defaultaddspace]
 Ljung-Box-Test & 0,4936 & 0,7841 & 0,8457 & 0,8822 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

which results in the following table:

[image: Result of above code]

I would like to establish some hierarchy by indenting the "Ljung-Box-Test" text within the first column (I will be adding more currency pairs / categories below).

Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can add the indent to all the cells in the first column (that should be left aligned) and remove the indent when you want it to:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption,booktabs,array}

\newcommand{\rowgroup}[1]{\hspace{-1em}#1}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\caption{Table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{>{\quad}lcccc}
\toprule
& \multicolumn{4}{c}{Lags}\\
 & 5 & 10 & 15  & 20 \\
\midrule
\rowgroup{EUR/USD} \\
Ljung-Box-Test & 0,4936 & 0,7841 & 0,8457 & 0,8822 \\
Foo-Test & 0,4936 & 0,7841 & 0,8457 & 0,8822 \\
Foo-Box-Test & 0,4936 & 0,7841 & 0,8457 & 0,8822 \\
\midrule
\rowgroup{USD/EUR} \\
Ljung-Box-Test & 0,4936 & 0,7841 & 0,8457 & 0,8822 \\
Foo-Test & 0,4936 & 0,7841 & 0,8457 & 0,8822 \\
Foo-Box-Test & 0,4936 & 0,7841 & 0,8457 & 0,8822 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's not really clean, but I added a blank column on the left, I aligned the second column (with `Ljung-Box-Test`) right, and for the `EUR/USD` it's a multicolumn, aligned left...

Here is the code :

```
\begin{table}
    \caption{Table}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{rrcccc}
        \toprule
        & &\multicolumn{4}{c}{Lags}\\[\defaultaddspace]
         & & 5 & 10 & 15  & 20 \\[\defaultaddspace]
         \multicolumn{2}{l}{EUR/USD} &  &  &  &  \\[\defaultaddspace]
         & Ljung-Box-Test & 0,4936 & 0,7841 & 0,8457 & 0,8822 \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

And it produces this : [image: My solution]

I hope this fits your wishes...

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, there is a simpler way by using `\hspace` function, like `\hspace{5mm}`. More info in [How do I indent text within a tabular environment?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/359677/131863)

Using `\rowgroup` is problematic with the `tabular` package, because you cannot use some functions like `\resizebox{}`.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Thank you for suggesting this answer. You might want to write [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your solution.