# How do I indent text within a tabular environment?

Tags: tables, indentation, r

I'm trying to create a table in r markdown where the age groups such as 0-20 and 21-55 are indented:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{lccc}
\toprule
Factors & 2 & 2 & P-Value\\
\midrule
Age\\
0-20 & 2 & 2 & 2\\
21-55 & 2 & 2 & 2\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

I've tried using spaces, \indent, \hspace, \rowgroup (didn't compile in r markdown). Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please tell us by *how much* certain cells should be indented. Incidentally, did you mean "indented" or "right-aligned"?

Comment: indented over a few characters, so that it looks like the age groups are a subset of Age

Comment: you have specified that the first column is flush left, you could use `c` instead, or use `\ ` or ...

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You could insert an `\hspace{<some length>}` directive at the start of cells. In the example below, I've set the length to `3mm`; you're obviously free to choose a different length.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabular}{@{}lccc@{}}
\toprule
Factors & 2 & 2 & P-Value\\
\midrule
Age\\
\hspace{3mm}0--20 & 2 & 2 & 2\\
\hspace{3mm}21--55 & 2 & 2 & 2\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\newcommand*{\tabindent}{ \hspace{3mm}}` to reduce LaTex code duplication

Comment: @DavidC. - That's definitely good advice if lots of indenting needs to be performed.

Answer (score 11):

A slight improvement for the alignment of the left column (on the `endash`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabular}{@{}rccc@{}}
\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{l}{Factors\hspace*{0.25em}} & 2 & 2 & P-Value\\
\midrule
\multicolumn{1}{l}{Age}\\
0--20 & 2 & 2 & 2\\
21--55 & 2 & 2 & 2\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1. I thought about aligning the age groups on the en-dash symbols as well, but I didn't do so as the OP didn't seem to care about this aspect of the table. I think your solution looks better...

Answer (score 4):

For me I like the simplicity of @Bernard and the indentation of @Mico, so I combined the two solutions:

```
    \begin{tabular}{@{\hspace*{1.8em}}lccc@{}}
    \toprule
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{Factors\hspace*{-1.8em}} & 2 & 2 & P-Value\\
    \midrule
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{Age}  & 2 & 2 & P-Value\\
                      0--20  & 2 & 2 & 2\\
                      21--55 & 2 & 2 & 2\\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
```

Comment: This is an excellent solution which I am now using, thank you. It seems the hspace after "Factors" doesn't do anything and is unnecessary.